# What MAC (Message Authentication Code) algorithms supported on OpenSSL?

Tags: openssl

What MAC (Message Authentication Code) algorithms supported on OpenSSL?

I found hmac and gost-mac (ccgost). Others ?

Comment: If you need more than HMAC and the upcoming CMAC, then checkout [Crypto++](http://www.cryptopp.com/). Its got 7 or 8 of them, including HMAC, CMAC, GMAC, VMAC,  CBC-MAC, DMAC ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What MAC (Message Authentication Code) algorithms supported on OpenSSL?

HMAC, GMAC and CMAC. GMAC is part of GCM; while CMAC is supported in the upcoming OpenSSL 1.1.0, which is available in Master.

You also have traditional signatures.

OpenSSL provides an example of using HMAC, CMAC and Signatures on its Wiki at [EVP Signing and Verifying](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Signing_and_Verifying). For GMAC, you have to turn to [EVP Authenticated Encryption and Decryption](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Authenticated_Encryption_and_Decryption) and *just* use the AAD feature of the mode.